# Hide Super Users from Admin

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

In Joomla 1.5 when going to the User Manager, Administrators could not see Super Administrators.

In a site I'm working on in Joomla 2.5 I'd like this to be the same way, what permissions do I change so that when Administrators go to the User Manager they are unable to see the Super Users?

I found in "Global Configuration > Permissions" that I can deny the Administrator from editing the Super Admin/User but the Administrator can still see the Super Users in the User Manager. Is there a way to hide the Super Users from the Administrators in the User Manager?

Comment: I don't know that you can make them invisible but they all will not be editable except by other super admins.  The managers let you see things including users.

Comment: I know that admin can't edit the super user, but I want the super user to be invisible. Can you help?

Comment: You could do a layout override for that view and just dd a condition check around the rows.  Or to get more complez you could change the model.

Answer (score 1):

To the php Myadin select database; "#_core_acl_aro_groups" and delete it "Super Administrator"

Super easy